# Laravel 5.7 redirect back with() message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Trying to redirect to the previous page with message when user doesn't have enough balance.
Controller:

```
if ($balance[0] > $kitap_baha[0]) {

    $userkitap = new UlanyjyKitap();
    $userkitap->user_id = Auth::id();
    $userkitap->yarysh_id = $id;
    $userkitap->save();

    $galan = $balance[0] - $kitap_baha[0];
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    $user->balance = $galan;
    $user->save();

    return response()->download($downloads[0]);
} else {
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Balansyňyz ýeterlik däl');
}
```

View:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <strong>Bagyşlaň!</strong> {{ session('status') }}
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Result of `dd($balance, $kitap_baha);` is:

```
 Collection {#311 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => 7.0
  ]
}
Collection {#303 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => 10.0
  ]
}
```

`$balance` - user's balance
`$kitap_baha` - book's price

It returns correctly, but i think there is no session in view.

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Use `return redirect(...)->with(...)` or `return back()->with(...)`; might be an issue with chaining them.

Comment: it didn't help    `return back()->with('status', 'Balansyňyz ýeterlik däl');`

Comment: Ok; wasn't sure if chaining those methods would mess with the logic, seems not to. Is your comparison correct? Do a `dd($balance, $kitap_baha);` in your Controller and verify that your comparison is correct/functioning as expected. Update your question with the result of `dd($balance, $kitap_baha);` also, if you can.

Comment: I did it, all things are correct, $balance and $kitap_baha are correct

Comment: OK... Can you post the result of `dd($balance, $kitap_baha);` or no? I won't be able to help further if you don't (don't see anything wrong with any other parts of the question)

Comment: `Collection {#311 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => 7.0
  ]
}`

Comment: `Collection {#303 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => 10.0
  ]
}`

Comment: Sigh... Don't post those as comments; edit that into your question please... But, that aside, it looks like it should be hitting the `else` statement, so session values should be getting set. Any errors in `storage/logs`?

Comment: `$kitap_baha` - price of the book, `$balance` - user's balance

Comment: Edit those 3 comments into your question as clarification; they'll get buried in the comments. (In fact they already are)